# Как подобрать такое регулярное выражение?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть текст:

> ВЕРТОЛЕТ АККУМ РУ 33008 24ШТ4 В ПЛАСТИК.БОКСЕ 281012СМ

Какая должна быть регулярка что бы вытащить 33008?
Естественно варианты текста всегда рандом, как и 33008.

Comment: Неужели `\d+` не работает?

Comment: Вряд ли решаемо в общем виде. Что будете делать с "МОДЕЛЬ САМОЛЁТА 1: 72 ПЛАСТИК" или "ДИЛДО 18 СМ СИЛИКОН" или "КРЫШКА СТЕКЛЯННАЯ 280 ММ"?

Comment: А если будет текст "БУТЫЛКА ПЛАСТИКОВАЯ 1,5 Л  1ШТ АРТИКУЛ:АРМИЯ" ? Как вытащить?

Comment: Как мне кажется, вам стоит более подробно описать, какими именно признаками набор символов `33008` выделяется среди остальных символов строки.

Answer (score 0):

Варианты для Python re и grep

```
echo "ВЕРТОЛЕТ АККУМ РУ 33008 24ШТ4 В ПЛАСТИК.БОКСЕ 281012СМ" \
| grep -Po "(?<=\s)[0-9]*(?=\s)"
33008
```

Answer (score -1):

Выборка всех чисел из строки:

```js
var num = parseInt("ВЕРТОЛЕТ АККУМ РУ 33008 24ШТ4 В ПЛАСТИК.БОКСЕ 281012СМ".replace(/\D+/g, ""));
alert(num);
```

Comment: Ну так, вопрос в любом случаи останется открытым, ибо надо вытянуть только первое число..

Comment: @entithat эх, если бы можно было утверждать наверняка, что оно первое...

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev, да, тут спорный момент. Поэтому стараюсь не давать ответы на такие (неточные) вопросы.

Comment: @entithat вы всё харните в одной строке?)

Comment: @IlonMask, что, простите?)